# Django - Linking Models

Tags: django, django-models

I am using django and I want to link two models. The first model is comment and the second model is image. I want to have multiple images for one comment and an image should be linked with only one comment.

Comment model has its fields and image model looks like this:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=f'{hash(id)}/', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image.name
```

And this is the model that I used to link comment and image:

```
class CommentImage(models.Model):
    comment = models.OneToOneField(Comment, models.CASCADE, null=True)
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image, models.CASCADE, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-id"]
        verbose_name = _("Image")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Images")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image.image.name
```

Here is the admin panel of django:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txRoT.png)

As you can see I could be able add only one image and there is no button as well to add multiple image. What should I change to be able to add multiple images?

I have tried using ManytoManyField and removing comment field from CommentImage but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating things. Why not just add a text field to your `ImageComment`:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    def upload_to(self, filename):
        return f'{hash(self)}/{filename}'

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to, null=True, blank=True)
    comment = models.ForeignKey(
        'ImageComment', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image.name


class CommentImage(models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField()
```

Or in case an `Image` can have multiple `ImageComment`s as well, use a `ManyToManyField`:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    def upload_to(self, filename):
        return f'{hash(self)}/{filename}'

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to, null=True, blank=True)
    comments = models.ManyToManyField(
        'ImageComment'
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.image.name


class CommentImage(models.Model):
    comment = models.TextField()
```

You can even add an `InlineModelAdmin` to make editing comments at the same location as the image possible:

```
from django.contrib import admin


class ImageCommentInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ImageComment


@admin.site.register(Image)
class ImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [
        ImageCommentInline,
    ]
```

Comment: I have tried your solution by adapting to my project. Basically, I have deleted the CommentImage model and merged it with Comment model. Since Comment model had comment field, I did not added it but added image like this:

image = models.ForeignKey(Image, models.CASCADE)

For admin.py, I have just added include image to Comment Admin. This did not changed anything. I still can add only one image for every comment.

I just want to see that it has an add button on the django admin panel by image's side so that it proves I can add multiple images.

Comment: @OğulTütüncü: multiple images *per comment*? That looks a bit "odd"...

Comment: Why is that odd? I want to have multiple images for one comment.

Comment: @OğulTütüncü: usually you want to have multiple comments, for one image...

Comment: But this time it is vice versa :D

Comment: @OğulTütüncü: then you add a `ForeignKey` from `Image` to `ImageComment`. In case there can be multiple comments on an image, and an image can have multiple comments, it is a `ManyToManyField`.

Comment: How would I show my images on the comment? What should I add to admin.py?

Comment: I figured it out by adding inline to Comment. Thank you for your help. I wish you a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this via manytomanyfields:

```
class CommentImage(models.Model):
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image, models.CASCADE)

class Comment(models.Model):
    # other fields here
    images = models.ManyToManyField(Image, through='CommentImage', related_name='comments')
```

Comment: I am getting this error while doing "python manage.py makemigrations":

TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable